# Update minimum spanning tree if edge is added

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, runtime, big-o

I have a possible solution for the following question, but not sure if correct:

Assume we have already found a minimum spanning tree `T` for a weighted, undirected graph `G = (V,E)`. We would like to be able to efficiently update `T` should `G` be altered slightly.

An edge is added to `G` to produce a new graph. Give an algorithm that uses `T` to find a minimum spanning tree for the new graph in `O(|V|)` time.

My algorithm:

```
for each vertex do
   if smallest edge not in T then
      replace this edge with existing edge in T
      break
   end if
end for
```

I do not have much experience in writing pseudocode, so my algorithm might be over-simplified or incorrect. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Don't know if the algorithm is correct, but it seems to me O(|E|), not O(|V|). Unless you can check the smallest edge in O(1).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't know if your algorithm is correct, but it doesn't seem `O(|V|)` at least, because getting the "smallest edge not in T" of a vertex cannot be done in `O(1)`.

The most usual way to add an edge `e=(u, v)` into a MST `T` is:

- Run a BFS in `T` from `u` to `v` to detect the edge with maximum value in that path. (`O(|V|)`)
- If that edge's weight is greater than the weight of the edge you're trying to add, remove that old edge and add the new one. Otherwise, do nothing, because the new edge would not improve the MST. (`O(1)`).

The rationale behind this solution is that simply adding the edge into `T` would create exactly one cycle, and to restore the MST property you have to remove the edge with maximum value from that cycle.

Comment: @ Juan Lopes - "to detect the edge with maximum value in that path" - Wouldn't this be max value of the existing spanning-tree edge in that path? Do we care about the non-spanning-tree edges in the path! Also, wouldn't BFS/DFS run in O(V+E) ?

Comment: @KGhatak But it is specified in the answer: "Run a BFS in `T`", where `T` is the spanning tree.

Comment: @JuanLopes `remove that old edge and add the new one` I was thinking about this statement. I feel that this might involve a bit of work. Suppose in the actual graph G the minimum edge weight is 1 and addition of a new edge (of weight 1) forms a cycle of with 3 vertices, each with edge weight 1. So simply removing the max weight edge in G and adding the min weight edge, I feel won't work. We need to check the possibility of formation of cycle (after removing the max edge in T and adding the new edge in T with lesser weight). This above way also deals with max edge weight in T which is a bridge

Comment: This checking of the presence of cycle in the tree can be probably efficiently using disjoint set DS with path compression and union by rank heuristic. We need to make and query this disjoint set DS on the vertices.After removal of the max edge (let the tree be T'), we build this DS in for V vertices. Find the connected components in T'. and query about the newly added edge (u,v). if the end points of u and v belong to the same set, then we cannot add it or else add it to combine the two components in T'. Total time= O(Vα(V)) where  α is the inverse ackermann function, which <=4 in practice

Comment: So the complexity is not hurt, but the steps in the algo increases. Please correct me if I am making a mistake.

Comment: The answer isn't about removing the max edge in G. You have to remove the max edge in the path u -> v in the MST. Each edge in the MST is a bridge. Each pair of vertices in T have a single path between them (because it's a tree). When you remove the max edge, you end up with exactly two components A and B. No other edge in G could take it's place (otherwise it would be in the MST)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your algorithm seems to be correct. I would amend your pseudocode to clarify that "if smallest incident edge not in T then" so that your new algorithm is this:

```
for each vertex do
   if smallest incident edge not in T then
      replace this edge with existing edge in T
      break
   end if
end for
```

**Proof by contradiction:**

There exist two cases: the new edge is either in the MST or it isn't. For the case that it is: Suppose that the algorithm does not replace an edge in T. This must mean that all edges in T are smaller than other edges that are incident on the same vertex. This is a contradiction because that means the new edge is not in the MST of T.

The proof for the other case is a trivially similar proof by contradiction.